# Prepared statement not working and not showing error

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, prepared-statement

I want to fetch data from the database by using a prepared statement but it failed and not even showing any error.  I used this but still not working `$result15->close();` Help me to write this code.

```
<?php
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id  FROM detail WHERE id = ?  LIMIT 10";
    $result15 = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    $result15->bind_param("i",$id);
    $result15->execute();
    $row151=$result15->get_result();
?>

               
<?php
  while($res15 = $row151->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<tr>
<td><a href="post?id=<?php echo  base64_encode(urlencode($res15->id))?>&<?php echo $res15->addpage;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $res15->post_name;?></a></td>
</tr>

<?php
 }
 $result15->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$res15->id` should be `$res15['id']` since you used `fetch_assoc()`, not `fetch_obj()`.

Comment: And you need to add columns like `addpage` and `post_name` to the `SELECT` statement

Comment: You should be getting "Trying to get property of non-object" warnings from that code.

Comment: Please turn on [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/231316) and [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/231316) error reporting.

Comment: what is the value of `$id`? Your code doesn't show this value as being set

Comment: @ChrisHaas It may be better to encourage the OP to [**output their errors to the log file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) rather than to screen  `;-)`

Comment: @Barmar I used this  but didn't work $res15['id']

Comment: Did you set `$id` first? Are you sure there are rows in the table with that ID?

Comment: What output are you getting? Are you getting anchors with empty `?id=`, or are you getting no anchors at all?

Comment: @Martin, although I agree in general, for development I strongly encourage loud, proud and in-your-face error messages. Log files are great if people actually check them, but people will actually fix "object doesn't support method XYZ" if they see it on a screen!

Comment: @ChrisHaas are you saying the White Screen of Death doesn't give enough information?! `:-D` . I can see that in a testing enviornment yes it's easier to have it all error data on screen, but I think it's worth noting that error logging is a better way, for the OP to explore that should they wish to `:-)`

Comment: @Martin it doesn't really matter as the certain media is not relevant to the question. the code must be written the way that it throws an error. While how this error will be processed is outside of the scope of this code and this question